# Sharepoint 2007 Column Filtering breaks when new field added

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Wondering if anyone has seen this before.

We have a sharepoint site we maintain that contains records of job applicants.

If we ever add a new field to the list all of the filtering on the site breaks until we go through and update each new record in some way. We dont have to set a value for the new field, we just have to change A field, ANY field and re-save the record. Then filtering comes back.

We have taken toward keeping a field on each candidate called "Maintenance" that we flip from 0 to 1 and back each time we make an update. It's quite annoying.

Any idea why sharepoint breaks filtering when you add a new field and how I can permanently resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there were column indexes on several of the fields. When we updated the record programatically it broke the indexing which resulted in the filters not working. we dropped and re-added the indices and it worked.